# jQuery horizontal slide toggle navigation

Tags: jquery, navigation

I'm looking to make a simple nested navigation menu that "slides" or "flys" out horizontally-left on hover. I assume the only way to achieve this is with jQuery so I have been playing around with it.

**Initial State**

[image]

**Hover State**

**EDIT:** I realize this picture looks a bit wrong. I want the entire ul.sub-menu (ie: PEOPLE & APPROACH) to slide out together, not sequentially.

[image]

The general structure is:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li>ABOUT
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>PEOPLE</li>
            <li>APPROACH</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>PROJECTS</li>
    <li>CONTACT</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

My jQuery is:

```
$("nav li").on('hover', function(){
    $(this).children(".sub-menu").animate({width: 'toggle'});
});
```

Currently my li's are floated.

My issue is when I hover over the parent LI, the .sub-menu fades in but is down a line and everything is jumping around due to floats.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you were going for? You were missing a `display:inline-block` property from your CSS I believe. By using an inline block, each element with that property will retain block features (width, height, etc) but also remain inline (no breaks before or after). Without the block part, it makes no sense to apply a width modification.

## CSS:

```
<style type='text/css'>
    nav li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
    }

    .sub-menu {
        display: inline-block;
        white-space: nowrap;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
```

## Javascript:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.sub-menu').hide();

        $('.link').hover(
            function() {            
                $('.sub-menu', this).stop().animate({
                    width: 'toggle',
                    opacity: 'toggle'
                } /* [, duration in ms] */);
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

## HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="link">ABOUT
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>PEOPLE</li>
                <li>APPROACH</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="link">PROJECTS
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>ONE</li>
                <li>TWO</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>CONTACT</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Also, you don't need the width:100%. I just added that to make it easier to test. :)

Comment: Ahhh. I guess the biggest problem was the white-space: nowrap. That was causing the words to collapse and look all funky. Now I just need to figure out how to make the menu stay open when you hover on its children.

Comment: Modified for your latest request. Should now stay open until a user moves to a different parent li. Take a look at the modified HTML as well (this could ultimately be changed, but I think it illustrates the concept).