# Horizontal submenu sliding open between menu items

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a horizontal menu with horizontal submenu one on the left and one right, but when i align the menu with submenu on the right there is some weird twitching effect caused by the 'width' i think it only happens on the right. Does anyone know how to create a smooth sliding on hover horizontal submenu with opacity effect. Please a need help!

```
   $(function() {
    $('.sub-menu').hide();

    $('.link').hover(function() {            
            $('.sub-menu', this).stop().animate({
                width: 'toggle',
                opacity: 'toggle'
            } /* [, duration in ms] */);
        }
    );
});
```

[Demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/foroloca/zR5Tx/)

[Code used link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736005/jquery-horizontal-slide-toggle-navigation)

Comment: In the fiddle, I am not even able to see the links!!! **Edit:** Got the issue. Lemme check. :)

Comment: What do you mean? You can't see the submenu links on hover ABOUT?

Comment: I said I got it. Now check my answer in a moment.

Comment: Thank you i need this working it must be very simple but i can't get i work properly. :)

Comment: Yup, done. Check out my answer and see the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

#### Space is the issue.

In your fiddle, there is a space after the **About** and the `UL` after that has `inline-block`, so remove the space and give a `padding-left` to the `.sub-menu`. That fixes.

#### Fix:

```
​.sub-menu li:first-child {padding-left: 5px;}​
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zR5Tx/2/

Comment: show what, buddy? i have given the fiddle link there. check it out. http://jsfiddle.net/zR5Tx/2/

Comment: thank you i didn't see the link before i answered now i do. Let see if this works thank you so far!

Comment: I still have twitching after hover sliding back. Its weird :(

Comment: Hey, what browser are you using? I had it, but not after my fix.

Comment: google chrome works but it have to work also on the other browsers

Comment: If the issue is with the browser rendering engine, you can't help it... moreover, mac has the worst compatibility. ps: I am a front end engineer developing enterprise apps.

Comment: This is the best I can give you. I suspect if someone could give you an answer. But, I guess you can do this with CSS transitions, which will be much smoother, but I doubt it is not supported in IE and old browsers...

Comment: Check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_transitions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FUsing_CSS_transitions and http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/

Comment: i need the most supported solution for most of the browsers (don't care about the very old browsers). But css transitions aren't that supported just jet. And i'm not a programmer. But thank you for your help i have to let this idea go and do something else.

Comment: Okay, if you wish, and possible, and you feel that my time is worth, you can mark this answer. :) Thanks in advance. :)